# How to redirect page with symfony from one form to another using ajax passing to actions?

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony1, redirect

I am struggling for simple redirecting page in symfony using ajax...but before redirecting we must save the form ..i dno how to cal action using jquery ajax to save the form and redirecting to another form... i dno to handle this in symfony framework...

any one help me in prob...

Comment: Symfony 1.4 or Symfony2?

Comment: symfony 1.4 ..pls find me a solution immeditely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery: I would post your Form via `$.ajax` and pass the destination with Symfony's `url_for`. In the callback you could redirect to another action.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '<?php echo url_for('your/action') ?>', // where to post form data
    data: your_form_data,
    success: function() {
        // where to redirect
        location.href = '<?php echo url_for('route/toRedirectTo') ?>';
    }
});
```

Look at:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/UrlHelper#method_url_for

Comment: Thanks martin...I got solution...the same i used and for data: i got trouble and i used serialize() then as usual in action i do normal save and it works..but after that  validations error display doesnt work for my form....can u tel me y the validation error display doesnt work ???

Comment: First you should check if you really need AJAX here. Take a look at domi27's answer! If you really need it, you could check in the action for `if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())` and then return the validation errors in JSON format. On Clientside you need to parse the JSON and check maybe for `if(response.error)` and display the validation errors. Of `response.error` is false, you could do your redirect. Hope that helps!

Comment: i do normal validation ...but i dont understand symfony validations ...wher do these error msges wil be in symfony???validation form in symfony wher it is placed??

Comment: I do it like so: http://pastebin.com/Gi8233ss . Validation messages can be set inside /lib/form/doctrine/[file].php and then add `$this->getValidator('YOUR VALIDATOR NAME')->setMessage('required', "Please insert your name... or so...");` to the configuration() method.

Comment: Thanks martin this must be getting solution to me which i was currently looking for

Comment: Okay, and take a look at the Symfony tutorials like this: http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/10

Comment: public function executeAjaxtest(sfWebRequest $request)
{if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
{//form values binding
    if ($this->form->isValid())
{
  
     $this->form->save();
     $this->redirect('registration/ajaxtest');
     }
     else 
     {
     echo "validation failed";
     $this->redirect('registration/contact');
}}}}this is my controller ...when form does not valid it jus redirected and how can print error msg from this action method

Comment: `echo "validation failed"` is not enough. Returning only Text to your JS will work like this: `return $this->renderText('err');`

Comment: tats great martin..i used echo for just checking and here am submitting whole form in jquery ajax how can i figure out error in particular field ex:i got error in email i can i rendor it seperately

Comment: Check my pastebin! I'm iterating every field. The name is in `->renderLabelName()` and the error in `->getError()`. Check http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfFormField.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO not everything must be done with AJAX.

> ... to save the form and redirecting to another form ...

You can handle your form request as usual with the corresponding action

```
if($form->isValid()){
     /* 
      do things 
     */

     $this->redirect("routeto/nextform");
}
```

Otherwise take a look at **martin-b**'s answer

Comment: ya i got the solution domi...i passed data through ajax and saved in my action controller but nw the problem is form is getting validated but validation msg does nt displayed..i kept else statement and jus redirected the page ...if form is invalid it does nt show error msg ...can u tel me wats d prob??